# Why does npm install an older version of my specified depdency?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-workspaces

I have a file setup like

```json
/
/package.json                 /* workspace root */
/server/
/server/package.json          /* directly includes "is-plain-object": "^5.0.0" */
/client/
```

I run `npm i --workspace server`, which creates 2 separate node_modules folders:

```
/node_modules/
/server/node_modules/
```

Which is fine (I guess?), but in the root's `/node_modules/is-plain-object/` is version 5.0.0, whereas `/server/node_modules/is-plain-object/` is version 2.0.4

Looking at the lockfile (which was generated at the root of the repo), a couple dependencies of packages used in the server rely on `"is-plain-object": "^2.0.3",` and others rely on `"is-plain-object": "^5.0.0"`.

But, when I run the app, a dependency I'm using 'octokit' ([github](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.js)) throws an error

> TypeError: isPlainObject.isPlainObject is not a function

Looking in the 2.0.4 package, they have a default export of the function, whereas the 5.0.0 version is a named export, and looking at the octokit code it looks like they are looking for the named export, so I'm assuming this package is resolving to the 2.0.4 version.

So my questions:

1. Since I'm specifying 5.0.0 in my package.config, why is it pulling in 2.0.4?
2. Does npm have some mechanism for resolving situations where 2 packages with incompatible dependencies to be used within the same repo?
3. What is the purpose of the duplicate node_modules folders?

Answer (score 0):

> resolving situations where 2 packages with incompatible dependencies to be used within the same repo?

Yes, not even talking about workspace, you may have incompatible transitive dependencies, and npm is able to import different versions so that your dependencies' own dependencies match their spec. Typically, this will result in `node_modules` folders in each dependency if necessary.

```
/node_modules
  /module-a
    /node_modules
      /dep-module (version 5.0.0)
  /module-b
    /node_modules
      /dep-module (version 2.0.4)
```

Comment: That makes sense; doesn't seem to explain why npm is splitting up the two versions in my case, nor why it's resolving the wrong version for the code run by octokit (the code being global and run when the module is loaded)